# How do you append a string to an image url?

Tags: jquery, html

I feel really stupid for asking this question, but I have been looking every for an answer but couldn't find the code I was looking for.

All I would like to do is add a string to an existing image url.

Before:

```
<div class="blog1"><img src="example.jpg"></div>
```

After: `<div class="blog1"><img src="example.jpg?Action=thumbnail&Width=80&Height=80"></div>`

Thanks for the help!! The solution works!!

Comment: Have you tried anything in particular yet?

Comment: Not really -   $('img').attr('src', 'image-thumb.jpg'); comes close to what I need accept I will need it to be appended instead of replaced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.blog1 img').attr('src', function(){
  return this.src + "?Action=thumbnail&Width=80&Height=80";
});
```